# Differences between imperative and declarative programming languages?

Tags: declarative, paradigms, imperative-programming

I know what they are:

> In an imperative programming language you tell the compiler what you want to happen step by step, whereas in a declarative language you write code which describes the result but not necessarily how to achieve the desired result.

However, I wan't to know the optimisations of using either type of programming language. As well as this - are there any complications involved? For example the need of space/time in running a program developed in either language.

Comment: I would say the answer to this would take up an entire book, or several.

Comment: @biziclop I just need some small examples to help wrap the whole idea around my head haha

Comment: You'd need to narrow it down, either in terms of languages or in terms of problems, preferably both.

Answer (score 2):

The *Performance Comparison* section of [Comparison of programming paradigms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_paradigms) WikiPedia page pretty much covers what you are asking in a general way.

> Purely in terms of total instruction path length, a program coded in
>   an imperative style, without using any subroutines at all, would have
>   the lowest count. However, the binary size of such a program might be
>   larger than the same program coded using subroutines (as in functional
>   and procedural programming) and would reference more "non-local"
>   physical instructions that may increase cache misses and increase
>   instruction fetch overhead in modern processors.
>
> The paradigms that use subroutines extensively (including functional,
>   procedural and object-oriented) and do not also use significant
>   inlining (via compiler optimizations) will, consequently, use a
>   greater percentage of total resources on the subroutine linkages
>   themselves. Object oriented programs that do not deliberately alter
>   program state directly, instead using mutator methods (or "setters")
>   to encapsulate these state changes, will, as a direct consequence,
>   have a greater overhead. This is due to the fact that message passing
>   is essentially a subroutine call, but with three more additional
>   overheads: dynamic memory allocation, parameter copying and dynamic
>   dispatch. Obtaining memory from the heap and copying parameters for
>   message passing may involve significant resources that far exceed
>   those required for the state change itself. Accessors (or "getters")
>   that merely return the values of private member variables also depend
>   upon similar message passing subroutines, instead of using a more
>   direct assignment (or comparison), adding to total path length.

...it goes on

Comment: And it isn't even true in all cases.

Comment: @biziclop in general what kind of cases would it not apply to?

Comment: @madcrazydrumma That's what I'm trying to say: there is no "in general", the two families of languages are far too diverse to derive any meaningful and universal differences on this level. It all depends on the specific language, and the specific environment. (For example, most modern Java VMs **do** use extensive inlining, making a lot of that paragraph mostly irrelevant in Java's case. But you could end up coding on a platform where JIT compilation is even better, or non-existent.)

Comment: With all due respect, I think you've misread that paragraph @biziclop -  It doesn't say that functional, procedural and oo languages do not use inlining.   It says languages which are functional, procedural and oo and ALSO don't use inlining.  so the Java case you mention is covered.
...although I get your point about generalization.

Comment: @RossDrew I get that, I may have worded it wrong though. I'm not saying that paragraph is wrong, just that it doesn't apply to a lot of imperative languages for the reasons outlined in it. And even within the same language, it may depend on the running environment.

Comment: @biziclop Regardless, we are agreed that it's hard to be general with such abstract concepts but my answer is meant as a starting point at least. :)